# Text file search tool for Windows (command line) with an extremely large pattern list

Tags: windows, algorithm, search, full-text-search, findstr

Is there an efficient way to search a list of strings from another text file or from a piped output?

I have tried the following methods:

```
FINDSTR /G:patternlist.txt <filetocheck>

or
Some program whose output is piped to FINDSTR

SOMEPROGRAM | FINDSTR /G:patternlist.txt
```

Similarly, tried GREP from MSYS, UnixUtils, GNU package etc.,

```
GREP -w -F -f patternlist.txt <filetocheck>

or
Some program whose output is piped to GREP

SOMEPROGRAM | GREP -w -F -f patternlist.txt
```

For example, Pattern List file is a text file which contains one literal string per line.

For example

```
Patternlist.txt
65sM547P
Bu83842T
t400N897
s20I9U10
i1786H6S
Qj04404e
tTV89965
etc.,
```

And the file_to_be_checked  contains similar texts, but there might be multiple words in a single line in some cases.

For example

```
Filetocheck.txt
3Lo76SZ4 CjBS8WeS
iI9NvIDC
TIS0jFUI w6SbUuJq joN2TOVZ
Ee3z83an rpAb8rWp
Rmd6vBcg
O2UYJOos
hKjL91CB
Dq0tpL5R R04hKmeI W9Gs34AU
etc.,
```

They work as expected if the number of pattern literals are less than 50000 and sometime works very slow upto 100000 patterns.

Also, the filetocheck.txt will contain upto 250000 lines and grows upto 30 MB in size.

The problem comes when the pattern file becomes larger than this. I have an instance of patternfile which is around 20 MB and contains 600000 string literals.

Matching this against a list or output of 250000 to 300000 lines of text literally stalls the processor.

I tried **SIFT, and multiple other text search tools**, but they just kill the system with the memory requirements and processor usage and make the system unresponsive.

I require a commandline based solution or utility which could help in achieving this task because this is a part of another big script.

I have tried multiple programs and methods to speed up, but all in vain like indexing the pattern file, sorting the file alphabetically etc.,.

Since the input will be from a program, there is no option to split the input file as well. It is all in one big piped command.

Example:

```
PASSWORDGEN | <COMMAND_TO_FILTER_KNOWN_PASSWORDS> >> FILTERED_OUTPUT
```

The above problem is in  part where the system hangs or take very long time to filter the stdout stream or from a saved results file.

*System configuration details if this will be any help:
I am running this on a modest 8 GB RAM, SATA HDD, Core i7 with Win 7 64bit and currently I do not have any better configuration available currently.*

Any help in this issue is much appreciated.

I am also trying to find a solution if not create a specific code to achieve this (help appreciated in that sense as well.)

Comment: Using grep with a large pattern file spews out unmatched lines. Whereas, findstr is able to do a proper match but uses up a lot of time.

Comment: For now, the solution I believe it to use the grep tool. Please mark it as **SOLVED** and thank you so much for reading the problem!!

Using grep on windows worked to an extent without any issues.

**There were some issues (extra newlines) with the pattern file which got corrected that caused the grep output to fail.** **FACE PALM!!**
Currently,
**grep is performing at an average of 7-8 seconds of execution time**

compared to 

**findstr's monstrous execution time of 285 seconds!!**

**Grep rulez!!!**